# Update Table based on Range start value and end value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I have a set of data that uses a primary key of month of the year by numerical value, e.x. Month 1, Month 3. I am trying to update my table and its values from the raw data set based on a user entered value for the start of the range and end of the range. I attempted to match an array that looks at the months column in the data dump, and then match it to the value for both the "month start" and "month end", and populate my table with those values, but no success.

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(AdWordsDataDump!A2:A424,Summary!$C$2,0)*AND(MATCH(AdWordsDataDump!A2:A424,Summary!$C$3,0)),"")
```

Cells containing Formula = Dashboard Table that should be dynamically updated based on user values for range start and range end. If no data, then leave cell blank

`AdWordsDataDump!A2:A424` = Month column containing raw data

`Summary!$C$2` = Range Start (E.x. Month 1)

And

`Summary!$C$3` = Range End (E.x. Month 3)

Am I on the right path or is there a better approach?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to extract & compare month (numeric value) from date? If yes you can simply use Month excel function.

Comment: The formula as you have it will either return the product of the two match formulas or blank. I don't think that's what you want. Try using a combination of INDEX and MATCH to extract values based on a key.

Comment: @EngineerToast I agree with you that INDEX and MATCH are better for this, but I'm looking for something along the lines of dynamically adding rows for however many months are between the Month Start and Month End. In this case, there are three months, so A12,A13,A14 would have their cells filled in order of Month 1, Month 2, Month 3. Would INDEX and MATCH work in this case?

Comment: If you want the data range to vary, you have two options: 1) Create a large data range (an actual table would be best) with formulas that evaluate to blank "" if they're needed OR 2) Use VBA to add / delete rows of formulas as needed. The formulas are easier to maintain and give instant results but the VBA gives cleaner results. Post a sample from your raw data and which method you'd prefer. I could throw together a formula to help get you started.